Antd Form.Item validator doesn't trigger while i change input value via side buttons
I have an input with validator for min / max values. Also there is a button which sets value as max value in this input. The button is out of this form.
I type in input value under min and an error message appears. After that i clicked a button which sets max value (and this value is in this min/max range) but error message doesn't disappear. I found out that validator doesn't work if i don't type directly in input and change it via side buttons.
<div className={`${styles.creditPointTable} d-flex`}>
                        <span
                          id={styles.payAllTotal}
                          onClick={() => {
                            paymentSum.setValue(+credit.earlyPayment);
                          }}
                        >
                          pay max{' '}
                          {formatCurrencyHelper(credit?.earlyPayment)}
                        </span>
                      </div>

<Form.Item
                              name="paymentSum"
                              valuePropName="option"
                              rules={[
                                {
                                  validator: (_, e) => {
                                    return paymentSum.value <=
                                      maxPaymentValue &&
                                      paymentSum.value >= minPaymentValue
                                      ? Promise.resolve()
                                      : Promise.reject('');
                                  },
                                  message: (
                                    <div className={styles.errorMessage}>
                                      {paymentSum.value < minPaymentValue
                                        ? `Min value is ${minPaymentValue}₽`
                                        : paymentSum.value > maxPaymentValue
                                        ? `Max value is ${maxPaymentValue}₽`
                                        : 'Type the correct sum'}
                                    </div>
                                  ),
                                },
                              ]}
                            >
                              <Input
                                value={paymentSum.value}
                                className={styles.formControl}
                                id="credit-amountPayment"
                                maxLength={7}
                                onInput={handlePaymentSum}
                                type="number"
                                {...paymentSum.forInput}
                              />

The validator should trigger when the value of input changed, even if its not changed by user.
how should i do this?

Found out the solution: I can just trigger the validation with form.validateFields(['paymentSum']);
